# Pre-commit hook skips files in directory

Tags: lint, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, sqlfluff

I'm trying to implement SQLFLUFF linter on a certain directory (models/market) on a repo. I'm using this command `pre-commit run --files models/market/`
what I see is that it is skipping .sql files inside the directory showing this message:

> sqlfluff-lint........................................(no files to
> check)Skipped

while this path includes multiple sql files.
here is the pre-commit-config.yaml file:

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff
    rev: 2.1.3
    hooks:
      - id: sqlfluff-lint
        verbose: true
        additional_dependencies: [
          'dbt-bigquery==1.5.1',
          'sqlfluff-templater-dbt==2.1.3'
        ]
```

it is worth noting that this path is not included in `.sqlfluffignore`

I tried various commands like the ones in here:
https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1173

What I expect is to have SQLFLUFF lint my sql files in a certain directory that it's path is mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `--files` argument takes *files* -- you've passed it a single *directory*

try instead `pre-commit run --files $(git ls-files -- models/market)`

and before you suggest "it should just recurse" there are special files in `git` that are directories -- notably submodules -- and there's special meaning for those files.

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Thank you anthony, can you please help me with this issue as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76847893/sqlfluff-doesnt-parse-dbt-macros-to-fix-even-though-they-are-not-ignored-in-sq